# What is monotouch-glue and why does it appear in Xamarin stack traces?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

Example

monotouch-glue.m line 1584
objc_skip_type

On Crashlytics, it may appear as the top level failing thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file you mention, `monotouch-glue.m`, is part of the Xamarin.iOS runtime code. It is a small amount of code that can be required to map native (ObjC) with managed (.NET) types.

Note that it does not mean the bug is in that file, e.g. a wrong binding can produce something that can't execute properly (invalid match). However that might be hard to diagnose. If you can create a test case and file a [bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) then someone will have a look into it.